# Failed to deploy maven project, no connector available

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, jboss, mysql-connector

I'm trying to deploy a maven project but I'm getting this error:

```
       ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 2.745 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2014-07-14T00:52:07+04:00
[INFO] Final Memory: 12M/222M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-deploy-plugin:2.5:deploy (default-deploy) on project myProject: Failed to deploy artifacts/metadata: No connector available to access repository myRepo (jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/) of type default using the available factories AetherRepositoryConnectorFactory, WagonRepositoryConnectorFactory -> [Help 1]
```

**My plugins/extensions include the following:

maven-compiler-plugin 3.1

maven-war-plugin 2.1.1

jboss-as-maven-plugin 7.1.1

maven-deploy-plugin 2.5

wagon-ssh 1.0-beta-7

** I've created a com/mysql/main folder under modules and I've modified the module file to include the mySQL connector name. Am I missing something?

I appreciate your help.

Comment: Why would you like to deploy to a MySQL database ? You seemed to misunderstand the deploy intention.

Comment: I'm new to mvn and JBoss, I want to deploy a web application with a mysql database, "mvn clean install package" is working fine. How can I deploy the app then?